# Download video from DailyMotion

Tags: video, downloading

Is there a way to download videos from DailyMotion? I do have the DailyMotion application on my phone (Canvas 2) but as far as I can see it doesn't provide any feature to download video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the official dailymotion [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dailymotion.dailymotion) from play store.

Click the download button as seen on the picture below. (left of HD)

[image]

Comment: Hi Roxan, Thanks for you answer. Actually the option is for sync the video which is equivalent to download. Its reaching at Ultimate goal of download to watch the video without internet connection. I couldn't realize that thanks again for your answer :)